# Elasticsearch LTR plugin sample model and features for LightGbm and catboost?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I am trying out elasticsearch ltr plugin. I found a linear model in plugins documentaion which looks like this in json format

```
POST _ltr/_featureset/performancetest/_createmodel
{
  "model": {
    "name": "lightgbm_model",
    "model": {
      "type": "model/gbdt",
      "definition": """
        {
          "num_leaves": 31,
          "objective": "lambdarank",
          "boosting_type": "gbdt",
          "metrics": "ndcg",
          "ndcg_eval_at": [5, 10, 20]
        }
      """
    }
  }
}
```

But I am unable to find similar examples for lightgbm and catboost.
Can anyone share some small example model and feature files because the format in which plugin acccepts is a specific json format for each model as far as I have understood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by [this issue](https://github.com/o19s/elasticsearch-learning-to-rank/issues/424) and [this one](https://github.com/o19s/elasticsearch-learning-to-rank/issues/194), I don't think either LightGBM or CatBoost are supported yet.

However, under certain circumstances (dense vectors with only numerical features), it looks like there's a way to [transform LightGBM to XGBoost](https://github.com/o19s/elasticsearch-learning-to-rank/issues/150#issuecomment-380718275) using [lgb2xgb](https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/c/403335/21/mjolnir/training/lightgbm.py).

Comment: No luck with this, I think you are right , only xgboost and ranklib are supported. I am also not able to find exact examples of a compatible feature and model file for xgboost as well

Comment: yes accepted the same but the problem still remains unsolved. If I can simply get even a sample feature set and model file for xg boost then I can work towards transformation